# Google Map APIs - Combining geolocation and cluster markers

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating a website for ad classifies. I would like the users to see where the location of the item is on a map near their location.

Using Google's JS code templates for Geolocation and Cluster Markers work separately, when added to the same JS, they don't work.  Is there a way to combine the JS for them to work on the same map?

Thanks in advance

Edit - I have added the JS codes

/* Geolocation */

```
   var map, infoWindow;
  function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
      zoom: 6
    });
    infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

    // Try HTML5 geolocation.
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        var pos = {
          lat: position.coords.latitude,
          lng: position.coords.longitude
        };

        infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
        infoWindow.setContent('Location found.');
        infoWindow.open(map);
        map.setCenter(pos);
      }, function() {
        handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
      });
    } else {
      // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
      handleLocationError(false, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
    }
  }

  function handleLocationError(browserHasGeolocation, infoWindow, pos) {
    infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
    infoWindow.setContent(browserHasGeolocation ?
                          'Error: The Geolocation service failed.' :
                          'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.');
    infoWindow.open(map);
  }
```

/* Map Clustering */

function initMap() {

```
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 6,
      center: {lat: 55.378052, lng: -3.435973}
    });

    var labels = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';


    var markers = locations.map(function(location, i) {
      return new google.maps.Marker({
        position: location,
        label: labels[i % labels.length]
      });
    });

    var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers,
        {imagePath: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m'});
  }
  var locations = [
    {lat: 55.633792, lng: -4.661550},
    {lat: 55.864239, lng: -4.251806},
    {lat: 55.614302, lng: -4.665554},
    {lat: 55.543781, lng: -4.664010},
    {lat: 55.551993, lng: -4.623667},
    {lat: -26.246920, lng: -4.523914}
  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit difficult to answer your question without any specific samples. you will need to combine the geolocation JS code onto the cluster markers, which is an obvious answer. So if you have a sample of your code, we will be able to help.